# What is inside this Jquery UI?

Tags: jquery-ui

This is demo slideshow:http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/. The transformation between the last two images, it makes the picture into a grid and animates it one by one. How can this be achieved?

My thought is that when there is a transformation, it will create many div elements, every div will use the same background image, and use background position, to make every div present a different area of that image, that way it looks like the image was taken apart into a grid. Just use .animate() in jQuery to make it animate or some CSS3 effect, like rotate or scale to generate the slide effect.

I do not know, is what i am thinking correct? Does anyone know the mechanism behind that effect?